# Css How to fix this? The search bar overlaps the side nav

Tags: css

Does anyone know the problem? This happens for some other pages!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IuSz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give searchbar `z-index:50` and `z-index:10` to sidebar. This way searchbar will stay beneath the sidebar.

Comment: Glad it helps! Please do not forget to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-left = width-of-nav whenever nav is visible(non-collapsible mode).
If you simply want the nav bar on top and the search bar to be not used then use`overflow: hidden` style to search bar/entire page content except nav.
Other way is to add `z-index` to change the stacking order.

Answer (score 0):

navbar :

position:'sticky'

main:

z-index:100